# Define a tensor of constants for tf.while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

I want to somehow maintain a list of constants in `tf.while_loop` that can support the following functions

1. I am able to read and write (multiple times) a constant value at an index
2. I am able to run `tf.cond` on it by checking its value at an index vs some constant

`TensorArray` would not work here since it does not support rewrites.
What other options do I have?

Comment: I suggest you migrate to TensorFlow2 as most people that will read you are probably using TF2

Answer (score 0):

You could just define a normal `Tensor` and update it with `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` like this:

```py
%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=tf.float32)
data_tensor = tf.zeros_like(data)
tensor_size = data_tensor.shape[0]

init_state = (0, data_tensor)
condition = lambda i, _: i < tensor_size

def custom_body(i, tensor):
  special_index = 3 # index for which a value should be changed
  new_value = 8
  tensor = tf.where(tf.equal(i, special_index), 
                    tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, [[special_index]], [new_value]),
                    tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, [[i]], [data[i]*2]))

  return i + 1, tensor


body = lambda i, tensor: (custom_body(i, tensor))
_, final_result = tf.while_loop(condition, body, init_state)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  final_result_values = final_result.eval()

print(final_result_values)
```

```
[2. 2. 2. 8. 2. 0. 2. 2. 0. 0.]
```